# configure cc1 include path

Tags: openldap, msys2, cc

still facing some strange compilation error while using MSYS2 mingw64 to compile OpenLDAP

I think it boils down to some win socket thing, currently facing 2 major errors during make depend and make

during make depend

cannot locate nt_err.c in servers/slapd/slapi ==> I resorted to copy nt_err.c from libraries/liblber/nt_err.c

Then came the fatal error while make depend in slapi. Command used by make depend: `make -w -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include depend`, it maybe because I have passed -I/usr/include in the main make depend

but still

```
Entering directory '/home/Jimmy/openldapsrc/openldap-2.4.46/servers/slapd/slapi'
../../../build/mkdep -l -d "." -c "cc" -m "-M" -I../../../include -I.. -I.        -I../../../include -I./.. -I.     plugin.c slapi_pblock.c slapi_utils.c printmsg.c slapi_ops.c slapi_dn.c slapi_ext.c slapi_overlay.c nt_err.c
In file included from slapi_utils.c:34:0:
../../../include/netdb.h:73:10: fatal error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
 #include <netinet/in.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

And actually I have seen a lot of similar errors, for example during make it will also give error in slapi like

```
No such file or directory
#include <sys/socket.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have checked with `pacman -Fs in.h socket.h` the output are as follow

```
msys/msys2-runtime-devel 2.10.0-2
    usr/include/cygwin/in.h
    usr/include/netinet/in.h
    usr/include/sys/socket.h
```

and I have msys2-runtime-devel installed. Nonetheless this reminded me that during ./configure output contained

```
checking sys/socket.h usability... no
checking sys/socket.h presence... no
```

so Ｉ tried to run `gcc -xc -E -v -` trying to determine what directory is included, however in MSYS2-MINGW64 it stopped at this

```
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-7.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/cc1.exe -E -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/ -D_REENTRANT - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
```

the cc1 gave no output, froze MSYS2 and I have to terminate cc1 from task manager.

Then I run directly `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/cc1.exe -E -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/ -D_REENTRANT - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64`

it returned

```
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw64/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64- w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../include
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include-fixed
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
```

Turns out the `#include <...> search` does not include the /usr/include directory of MSYS2, should have been `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../../usr/include`

I tried putting `ENV CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"` before ./configure, that caused more errors, many .h not usable but presence. and sys/socket.h is usable and presence.

So turns out -I/usr/include somehow did not pass into the compiler?

My Question is, is this configurable? Or is there something wrong with my setup?

OpenLDAP 2.4.46

MSYS2 20161025

Answer (score 0):

MSYS2 has three different toolchains with different purposes:

1. The msys-2.0.dll-based toolchain, which creates executables that use the POSIX emulation capabilities provided by msys-2.0.dll.  The main compiler is `/usr/bin/gcc` and it uses headers from `/usr/include`.  This is the toolchain to use if your program was written for a Linux or another POSIX-type operating system and you are finding it difficult to port it to Windows because it uses a lot of features not supported by Microsoft.
2. MinGW 32-bit toolchain.  This compiles native Windows software that can run on 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Windows.  The main compiler is `/mingw32/bin/gcc`.  To use this toolchain you must launch MSYS2 with the "MinGW-w64 32-bit Shell" shortcut or launch mingw32.exe.  This toolchain is *not* compatible with the headers in `/usr/include`, but it can use native Windows headers with interfaces defined by Microsoft, like `windows.h`.
3. MinGW 64-bit toolchain.  This toolchain is just like the 32-bit toolchain except the executables are 64-bit executables, and thus only work on 64-bit Windows.  It has its own shortcut in the start menu, and can also be launched with `mingw64.exe`.

I don't know anything about OpenLDAP, but if it is requiring a bunch of headers that the MinGW toolchains don't have, you could either try to port it to Windows or switch over to building it with the msys-2.0.dll-based toolchain.